# Why only first of two external scripts loads asynchronously using promises

Tags: javascript, html, asynchronous, promise

I'm trying to wait until two asynchronously-loaded external scripts finish loading. However, only the first external script loads; the second one never does.  The code:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Load Test</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      window.gapiLoaded = function () {
        console.log("window.gapiLoaded, typeof(window.gapiLoadFunc): ", typeof(window.gapiLoadFunc));
        if (typeof(window.gapiLoadFunc) == "function")
          window.gapiLoadFunc();
        }
      window.gisLoaded = function () {
        console.log("window.gisLoaded, typeof(window.gisLoadFunc): ", typeof(window.gisLoadFunc));
        if (typeof(window.gisLoadFunc) == "function")
          window.gisLoadFunc();
        }

      const gapiPromise = () => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        let x = window.gapiLoadFunc;
        window.gapiLoadFunc = resolve;
        console.log("typeof(x):", typeof(x), "typeof(window.gapiLoadFunc):", typeof(window.gapiLoadFunc))
        if (typeof(x) == "number")
          resolve();
      });

      const gisPromise = () => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        let x = window.gisLoadFunc;
        window.gisLoadFunc = resolve;
        console.log("typeof(x):", typeof(x), "typeof(window.gisLoadFunc):", typeof(window.gisLoadFunc))
        if (typeof(x) == "number")
          resolve();
      });

      async function wait_gapi() {
        console.log("start wait_gapi")
        await gapiPromise();
        console.log("end wait_gapi")
      }

      async function wait_gis() {
        console.log("start wait_gis");
        await gisPromise();
        console.log('end wait_gis');
      }

      const wait_gapiPromise = wait_gapi();
      const wait_gisPromise = wait_gis();
      const waitPromise = Promise.all([wait_gapiPromise, wait_gisPromise]);
      console.log("calling waitPromise.then()");
      waitPromise.then((results) => {
        console.log("wait done");
        return results;
      });

    </script>

    <script async defer src="https://apis.google.com/js/api.js"
      onload="console.log('onload gapi'); if (typeof(window.gapiLoaded) == 'function') window.gapiLoaded(); else window.gapiLoadFunc = 0;"
    </script>

    <script async defer src="https://accounts.google.com/gsi/client"
      onload="console.log('onload gsi'); if (typeof(window.gisLoaded) == 'function') window.gisLoaded(); else window.gisLoadFunc = 0;"
    </script>

  </body>
</html>
```

The javascript console output:

```
start wait_gapi
test3.html:21 typeof(x): undefined typeof(window.gapiLoadFunc): function
test3.html:41 start wait_gis
test3.html:29 typeof(x): undefined typeof(window.gisLoadFunc): function
test3.html:49 calling waitPromise.then()
test3.html:59 onload gapi
test3.html:8 window.gapiLoaded, typeof(window.gapiLoadFunc):  function
test3.html:37 end wait_gapi
```

It never shows "unload gsi" for example.  If I reverse the two external  tags, then "unload gsi" occurs and "unload gaps" does not.

I'm sure I have at least one misunderstanding here.  What is it?

Comment: Your script tags at the bottom are missing the closing > after the onload attributes.

Answer (score 0):

S. Walker found the embarrassingly simple problem - my script tags at the bottom were missing the closing > after the onload attributes!  Interestingly, the first script loaded okay anyway, and no syntax errors were flagged. Adding the > characters made it work for both scripts.

Comment: Browsers typically try to handle things like this and swallow the bad HTML. It’s likely that it was interpreting both script statements as a single tag and therefore whatever you put first loaded. You can usually catch this stuff using the browser Inspect to see what the HTML the browser is using sees.